# How to implement regex function in Microsoft bot composer

Tags: botframework

How to implement regex in Bot composer ?
Below I have a scenario where user can enter any thing like: Qna-1234, Qna-{1234} etc.
From above I want to display only 1234 in the response. How can I achieve this it will
be very helpful if provided some solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a workaround to achieve this requirement without regex. You can update the expected user responses section. You can define an entity to extract just an Id from user expressions. Refer below screenshots for details.

[image: Prompt for text]

[image: Update expected responses]

[image: Result - check in emulator]

Comment: @madanbehera can you please upvote/accept it , if it helped you. Can help others looking for a solution.

Comment: there is vote option I clicked on that but nothing happens.Could you please tell me where is the upvote option so that I will vote on that.

Comment: Next to the answer there is a tick to accept the answer. There is an upward arrow to upvote. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/bot-service/adaptive-expressions/adaptive-expressions-prebuilt-functions#regular-expression-functions) that adaptive expressions only have one regular expression function, and it returns a Boolean value. If you would like the Bot Framework team to create a new prebuilt function for you, you can make a feature request here: https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/new/choose

In the meantime, you can create your own custom actions by following these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/composer/how-to-add-custom-action